# Как правильно расставить запятые

Tags: пунктуация

Именно благодаря этим запретам, природа здесь до сих пор сохранилась в нетронутом виде.

Answer (score 2):

Обороты со следующими предлогами **могут обособляться или не обособляться:** ***благодаря**, *ввиду, в зависимости от, в нарушение, во избежание, во исполнение, в отличие от, вплоть до, в противовес, в противоположность, в связи с, в силу, вследствие, в случае* и другими. Всё зависит от воли автора предложения и от особенностей расположения оборотов с этими предлогами в предложении.
Оборот **обособляется, если** требуется обозначить его границы (чтобы предложение не выглядело двусмысленным).
Оборот **не обособляется, если** он входит в состав сказуемого или тесно связан с ним по смыслу. Есть и другие особенности обособления/не обособления таких конструкций, почитайте [здесь](http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/punctum_attach1).

Я бы не поставила запятую в предложении, которое Вы приводите. Частица ИМЕННО усилила выразительность оборота настолько, что никакое обособление не требуется. Кроме того, оборот стоит в начале предложения, не разделяет подлежащее и сказуемое, не вызывает двусмысленности.

Comment: Катя, здравствуйте! Отвечаем дружненько... Вы, как всегда, подробно.

Comment: Здравствуйте, Лара! Очень рада!

Answer (score 1):

Обстоятельство с предлогом благодаря в данном случае не обособляется. Природа сохранилась *почему? по какой причине?* благодаря запретам (из-за запретов).